# Getting an empty variable from API parsing

Tags: swift, api

I started to work with API and got some problems that I'm not able to fix.

That's code related to my problem:

```
// MARK: - ProPlayerElement
struct ProPlayerElement: Codable {
    let name, avatarfull, personaname: String?
    let fantasyRole: Int?
    let teamName: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, avatarfull, personaname
        case fantasyRole = "fantasy_role"
        case teamName = "team_name"
    }
}

typealias ProPlayers = [ProPlayerElement]
```

```
class ApiManager {
    
    static let shared = ApiManager()
    
    func getInformation(completion: @escaping (ProPlayers) -> Void) {
        let request = ApiType.proPlayers.request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, let players = try?JSONDecoder().decode(ProPlayers.self, from: data) {
                completion(players)
            } else {
                completion([])
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

```
var heroNames = [String] ()
```

```
    func heroesNames () {
        ApiManager.shared.getInformation { players in
            for i in 0..<players.count-1 {
                self.heroNames.append(players[i].name!)
            }
        }
    }
```

So, about the problem: when i use the last function (heroesNames) my variable doesn't save any info as if this function never existed at all.

I did some test and now I know that everything inside

```
ApiManager.shared.getInformation { ProPlayers in

}
```

works perfect but outside this expression zero results

added print((self.heroNames)) (and changed count-1, it was misprint) before append and after append, works fine

```
    func heroesNames () {
    ApiManager.shared.getInformation { players in
        for i in 0..<players.count {
            print("before append\(self.heroNames)")
            self.heroNames.append(players[i].name!)
            print("after append\(self.heroNames)")
        }
    }
}
```

> before append[] after append["TZY"] before append["TZY"] after
> append["TZY", "YrikGood"] before append["TZY", "YrikGood"] after
> append["TZY", "YrikGood", "Newsham"]

Comment: `for i in 0..<players.count-1 {` should be `for i in 0..<players.count {` unless you want to ignore that last (and maybe only) result.

Comment: could you add `print(\(self.heroNames))` just after the `for i in...{}`, and show us what it prints. I suspect you are calling `heroesNames()` then after that, printing `self.heroNames`. This will not work, because your function  `ApiManager.shared.getInformation...` is asynchronous.

Comment: my point was, after you use `func heroesNames()`, where do you `print` the `heroNames`, how do you do it, what is the context? As you can clearly see, the data is in `heroNames` inside the function. Now show us what you do outside the function, since this is the problem you are having.

Comment: i tried to use return with -> [String] and call the function in super.viewDidLoad(), got empty array. After that tried to go void like there and just call the function heroesNames() also in viewDidLoad and after that print my array; print(heroNames), didn't work too. Everything saves only inside the func heroesNames and I don't know how to save this data outside to use it further

Comment: yes, just as I suspected. The function `heroesNames()` is a asynchronous function, because `ApiManager.shared.getInformation` is a asynchronous function. All this is to say, you have to `wait` for the data to be in your variable `heroNamesheroNames`, before you can use it. In other words, use a completion handler for `func heroesNames()`, as you did for `ApiManager.shared.getInformation(...)`. Look up how to use asynchronous functions in Swift.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine i will do it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this, to deal with your asynchronous `func heroesNames(...)` :

```
 func heroesNames(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) { // <-- here
     ApiManager.shared.getInformation { players in
         completion(players.map{$0.name}) // <-- here
     }
 }
```

And use it like this:

```
 heroesNames() { names in
     print("\(names.count)") // for testing
     self.heroNames = names  // <-- only here, not before
     // alternatively
     // self.heroNames.append(contentsOf: names)
 }
```

Of course, you could do away with `func heroesNames(...)` and use this instead:

```
ApiManager.shared.getInformation { players in
    self.heroNames = players.map{$0.name}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the the ApiManager class should be like this.

```
class ApiManager {
    static let shared = ApiManager()
    
    func getInformation(completion: @escaping ( Result<ProPlayers, Error>) -> Void) {
        let request = ApiType.proPlayers.request

        // creating url session
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            if let error =  error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }else if let data = data {
               do {
                   let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProPlayers.self, from: data)
                   completion(.sucess(result))
                  } catch {
                   completion(.failure(error))
               }
           }
        }
       task.resume()
      }
   }
```

At `ViewDidLoad` function call the `heroesName()` api function

```
func heroesNames () {
    ApiManager.shared.getInformation { result in
        switch result {
            case .sucess(let res):
                for i in 0..<players.count - 1 {
                   self.heroNames.append(player[i].name)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // code for updating the UI with data in array
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Error in parsing the data or invalid uri", preferredStyle: .alert)
                 self.present(alert, animated: true){
                      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0){
                           alert.dismiss(animated: true)
                      }
                 }
                 break
             }

       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but still the same problem for me, just empty array

Comment: can you provide the url link so, that i can figure it out why the problem is happening

Comment: https://api.opendota.com/api/proplayers url on api and https://docs.opendota.com/#tag/pro-players web where i got this url